# How to concatenate property names and values?

Tags: typescript

If we have an interface ( major simplification )

```
interface User {
       Id: number;
       Firstname: string;
       Lastname: string;
       Age: number;
       Type: string;
    }
```

and current logic I am refactoring that builds a search string in the following manner:

```
    function formatSearchCriteriaText(user: User): string {
       let searchText = "Date:" + Date.now();
       //currently calls out every single property.
       searchText += (user.Id) ? ", Id: " + user.Id : "";
       searchText += (user.Lastname) ? ", Lastname: " + user.Lastname : "";
       searchText += (user.Firstname) ? ", Firstname: " + user.Firstname : "";
       searchText += (user.Age) ? ", Age: " + user.Age : "";

       searchText += (user.Type) ? ", Type: " + user.Type : "";
       return searchText;
   }
```

How best to concatenate property names and values to avoid listing every single property. Is this a step in right direction?

```
type UserType<T> = {
      [P in keyof T]: T[P] ? `$,{P as string}: {T[P]}` : "";
    };
```

Comment: Your `UserType` is not a step in the right direction unless you need to actually have a *type* more specific than `string`, but I really doubt that will be useful to you... what is the use case?  Do you care about the order of the properties in the search string? Do you need a special type for it?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for replying. Order is important, hope that's not a complication, and no special type is needed, string would do. And, yes, I am adding to search string only if the value is there.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, corrected. My example is a piece of  existing logic, so, yes, it was tested before. To answer your another question, we don't want to add null or undefined props to the search string.

Comment: @jcalz Sorry, that's a result of my logic simplifications, as I am trying to be as concise as possible.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, tested and it's fine now.

Comment: Okay, taking your word for it.  Object types do not have a built in key ordering (e.g., a `User` object could have `Age` as its first property) so you will need to at least have an array of property names to specify order.  Keeping that in mind, [this](https://tsplay.dev/W4QEXw) is one approach to simplify it. Note that this is essentially just JavaScript, since the types are more or less unaffected.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, that addresses my biggest question - how to avoid calling out every property. Please go ahead. Do you also mind showing how much would change if the order was unimportant?

Comment: If order weren't important you would just iterate the object in whatever order it happens to be in, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NaZoEm).  I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to spend any effort on writing a type like `UserType<T>` since you don't need the TypeScript compiler to know anything more than the fact that the output is a `string`.  So let's just work with `string`.

You can refactor the body of `formatSearchCriteriaText()` to perform the same serialization logic on each property, by mapping over them.  Since you care about the order, you will need to at least *mention* the property names in your function, if only to specify that order.  Perhaps like this:

```
function formatSearchCriteriaText(user: User): string {
  const keys = ["Id", "Lastname", "Firstname", "Age", "Type"] as const;
  return "Date:" + Date.now() + 
    keys.map(k => user[k] ? ", " + k + ": " + user[k] : "").join("");
}
```

So `keys` is an array of property names, and I've used a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to ask TypeScript to keep track of the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the elements, so it knows they are `"Id"`, `"LastName"`, etc., instead of just `string`.  Then we just `map()` over that array with your logic, where `k` is the key and `user[k]` is the value.  The reason TypeScript allows `user[k]` is because it knows that `k` is one of the property keys and that `user[k]` is a valid property and is of a serializable type like `string` or `number`.

You can verify that it works:

```
const u: User = {
  Age: 10,
  Id: 0,
  Firstname: "John",
  Lastname: "Doe",
  Type: "Plumber or something"
};
console.log(formatSearchCriteriaText(u));
// "Date:1701657535878, Lastname: Doe, Firstname: John, Age: 10, Type: Plumber or something"
```

If order were *not* important, you could forgo mentioning the keys and just iterate over the properties of `user` in whatever order they are stored, such as by using [the `Object.entries()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
function formatSearchCriteriaText(user: User): string {
  return "Date:" + Date.now() + 
    Object.entries(user).map(([k, v]) => v ? ", " + k + ": " + v : "").join("");
}
console.log(formatSearchCriteriaText(u));
// "Date:1701657535879, Age: 10, Firstname: John, Lastname: Doe, Type: Plumber or something"
```

That's even simpler, but you can see how the properties are not serialized in your desired order.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChnICSAJgFzIgCuAtgEbQDc+yAYsFOmCHNROZ1FABzJgQAycTt178wgkCOYBBIXwo16UUcgAqATwAOagcKYBfXLgQB7EJ2SVyGLAF4cy1eQCMABgA0zCTk-sxsHFw8agBEAFLWABYgUQHikhEyyFEAItYQycz6RuRRAAoANhpY1lDI6Na8YPHCUbhmTLjSEOgGiCgA8lDE0ITUBtVgcODuzDCUIAhgwLbIMNXUcGAAyhBwUAjxAMKCkIJwOhAAHmAAFJSYUE73AJSy8kLuBAQ2dmDIANYQPToZBuADaURIyUyEikkShUTCsN48JUeT8mUKeQAushJMhvpxtAQoBAwJQoCBMlkNnwosgANTIamQAB0IGsAHdrk8Gf9AegWesDNc-iCAHwOe6gv44gD8mXRdMZosZUWKvLu0GlOOKUSeLIAVtZQNconrtBYvrY6mUICyytYhNdVlB1lsdntDsdoMAzpcbpQnk9tAB6ENUmmkLwAdh8XgAbABWaOJgDMiYAHNGM+iYek1DkIOjEfnyHFEujUd5-LpDGpypUatVavVSU0FHTWpZOt1esgBkMoKgQMBRuNJr88DM5gslpSXW7trt9kdgCdfecrrd7o9oC9anJhB9PiSyRSI5BSEqmTS2Zzuby+rQDRAFiyIOBBF1t3vBXBhdc0rogAbliPIuBKwHIPK8K8iqmTqoyUG6vqRommawbMJa+LWtYtr2o6zprBsS6equ65+lugaYQQYYXnwMZxkmKbplmACclaeMgvjFuwSJqOWIC5mknTkIW6KYuQDZ0FUNR1A07ZCJ2FiWLgQA)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and explanations! It is in line with what I was looking and very close to how I would do it in .net realms. Plugged in Ordered version to my code base and it's working. The only confusion I had about "const" usage was under impression it's to support immutability.

Comment: Yes, re-tested, all good!